# How do know how many deep learning epochs were done, from R?

Tags: r, h2o

Early stopping is turned on by default for `h2o.deeplearning()`. But, from R, how do I find out if it did stop early, and how many epochs it did? I've tried this:

`model = h2o.deeplearning(...)
print(model)`

which tells me information on the layers, the MSE, R2, etc. but nothing about how many epochs were run.

Over on Flow I can see the information (e.g. where the x-axis stops in the "Scoring History - Deviance" chart, or in the Scoring History table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your model is called `m`, then to get just the number of epochs trained: `last(m@model$scoring_history$epochs)`

To see what other information is available (which is literally everything you can see in the Flow interface) and how to access it, use `str(m)`

Also be aware of this command: `summary(m)`  In addition to what is shown with `print(m)` it adds this section (for a deeplearning model):

```
Scoring History: 
            timestamp   duration training_speed    epochs iterations       samples training_MSE training_deviance training_r2
1 2016-04-14 11:35:46  0.000 sec                  0.00000          0      0.000000
2 2016-04-14 11:35:52  5.218 sec 15139 rows/sec  10.00000          1  77150.000000      0.00000           0.00000     0.07884
...
7 2016-04-14 11:36:18 31.346 sec 25056 rows/sec 100.00000         10 771500.000000      0.00000           0.00000     0.72245
```

I.e. You can see total number of epochs by looking at the last row.

BTW, this is different to h2o's `summary()` command when applied to a data *frame*; in that case it behaves like R's built-in summary function, and shows statistics on each column in the data frame.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite confident in stating that the answer of Darren Cook is valid only when `overwrite_with_best_model=FALSE`. Anyway, this parameter is set to be `TRUE` by default, so the previous answer can be quite misleading for reasons that you can partially find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207125/retrieve-the-optimal-number-of-epochs-when-using-early-stopping-in-h2o-grid). You can check what I mean in the following output obtained tuning the network with `h2o.grid` and using `m@model$scoring_history` as Darren suggested.

```
epochs     validation_classification_error
0.00000    0.46562
1.43150    0.50000
100.31780  0.46562
```

As you can see, if `overwrite_with_best_model=TRUE` than the functions saves the best model in the last iteration, thus solution of Darren always corresponds in the maximum number of epochs. Assuming that you are tuning your model, I recommend the following solution:

```
epochsList = m@model$scoring_history$epochs
bestEpochIndex = which.min(m@model$scoring_history$validation_classification_error)
bestEpoch = epochsList[bestEpochIndex]
print(sprintf("The best epoch is: %d", bestEpoch))
```

Comment: Good point - the point of both my question and my answer was wanting to know how many epochs were done before early stopping stopped it.  I find your stat - the number of epochs to reach the minimum of some metric - also interesting. Though, all of them should be used cautiously: you can easily vary +/-50% epochs to reach the same result from run to run.